# Multi-threaded java program preventing cpu from monitoring its own heat

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu-usage, threadpoolexecutor

Can a java program use all available threads and CPU power to the point where the CPU no longer detects its own heat?

I was working on a little project for learning purposes when I stumbled upon a weird behavior  that I didn't know was possible through Java.
For learning a little about multi-threading, thread safe and efficient math calculations I made a quick and dirty program to find prime numbers.

Problems began when I set the thread pool size to 12 and used all threads (6 core I7 hyperthreaded, specs will be below), what I found was my CPU wasn't reacting to its own temp rising, only when I stopped the program again did it notice and started to spin up the fans.

Specs of hardware involved:

- CPU: (6 core, 12 threads) I7-5820k at 3,3GHz
- Motherboard: Asus X99-DELUX
- CPU-Fan: NZXT Kreaken x61

Measuring software used:

- NZXT CAM
- CPUZ

Some tests I carried out to try and see what and why this is:
Ofc I needed to establish that this was really happening, so I opened both process manager, CPU-Z and CAM to monitor the CPU usage and heat, and sure enough, when I ran the code everything just seemed to freeze and stay at the same values (roughly around 35 C), but as soon as I stopped it, the temp rocketed up to near 70C.
Performing the same test with just 10 threads, leaving 2 treads untouched, the fans gradually increased with the temperature.

Here are the 3 main classes in this program:

A thread safe long
    public class SyncedLong {
        private long val;

```
    public SyncedLong(long val){
        this.val = val;
    }

    public synchronized void increment(){
        val++;
    }

    public synchronized long incrementAndGet(){
        val++;
        return val;
    }

    public synchronized long get(){
        return val;
    }
}
```

My ThreadControler class for storing and handling the active threads:

```
public class ThreadControler {

    ArrayList<PrimeCalculatorThread> primePool = new ArrayList<>();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public void increment() {
        if(executor.isTerminated()){executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);} //12 is the amount of threads on my cpu
        PrimeCalculatorThread pct = new PrimeCalculatorThread();
        primePool.add(pct);
        executor.execute(pct);

    }

    public void decrement() {
        PrimeCalculatorThread pct = primePool.get(primePool.size()-1);
        pct.terminate();
        primePool.remove(pct);
    }

    public void terminate() {
        for(PrimeCalculatorThread pct : primePool){
            pct.terminate();
        }
        primePool.clear();
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Finally the number cruncher, PrimeCalculatorThread

```
public class PrimeCalculatorThread implements Runnable {
    // 77263
    public static SyncedLong threaddedLong = new SyncedLong(0); //Startes a new SyncedLong at starting number 0.
    long currentNumber = 0;
    long lastNumber = 0;
    long a = 0;
    long b = 0;
    long c = 0;
    long startingNumber = 0;
    boolean foundPrime;
    boolean running = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            currentNumber = threaddedLong.incrementAndGet();
            foundPrime = true;

            if (currentNumber % 2 != 0) {
                a = 0;
                while (a <= currentNumber) {
                    b = a;
                    while (b <= currentNumber) {
                        c = a * b;
                        if (a != currentNumber && b != currentNumber) {
                            if (c == currentNumber) {
                                foundPrime = false;

                            }
                        }
                        b++;
                    }
                    a++;
                }
                if (foundPrime) {
                    Output.println("Found prime: " + currentNumber + "    Difference: " + (currentNumber - lastNumber) + "    " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    lastNumber = currentNumber;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void terminate() {
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Cpu Usage
[image: CPU usage]

---

English is not my native language so don't judge my formulation and grammatiks too harshly, please just drop a quick question if you feel something is phrased incorrectly or if it just doesn't make enough sense(if any).

Comment: "...leaving 2 treads untouched, the fans gradually increased with the temperature." - did you conclude this from the monitoring software of physically hearing or feeling air pushed by CPU cooler fan?

Comment: both, i was watching the monitored temperature and rpm as well as listening to my fans almost take off.

Comment: What operating system? I have an older computer, Intel DP67GB motherboard, 3770K 3.5 ghz cpu with 4 cores. I can run 8 threads at 100% cpu, with task manager properly displaying performance, and Intel desktop manager properly displaying each core's temperature, the overall cpu temperature and fan speed when running Windows 7 64 bit or Windows XP 32 bit.

Comment: What are the BIOS settings? In my case the 3770K tends to run hot, and the BIOS settings default to targeting a maximum temperature of 85C. When not under load, the 4 cores run at around 38C, and when under load, the fan doesn't speed up until the overall cpu temperature reaches about 78C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Modern intel technology is so advanced . Even if you think you are making use of all the cores and thread at the same time, at the hardware level the OS allocates and shares the processor. Now just to prove my fact try to play a video in the background while running this program, it should run( it may not be smooth) .

Inside the processor there is a technology that prevents the processor from burn due to overheating. First it will speed up the FAN and then ultimately it will shutdown the system of temperature keeps increasing .

Yes you are partially right, the FAN and cpuz takes some time to react. But if the temperature crosses a point the processor will raise an interrupt and hauls all activities..

Comment: The temperature monitored didn't change while the program was running, neither did the fans, however all 12 cores was hammering away at 100% (pic will be added). As well as the system, while running the code, would slowly degrade and eventually halt, leaving nothing working or moving. The fans and CPU-Z had no delay when I ran the test with less than 12 threads, in fact, the changes was instant,

Comment: tats because updating fan speed requires some calculations, since all cores are busy the fan speed remains constant. but if the temperature crosses a certain value it will interrupt and temporarily halt your program.

Comment: Hmm sounds logical. I wouldn't let the program run long enough for the build in thermal failsafe to kick in, in fear of damage to my CPU. Thanks for explaining :)